# Optimizing a regex expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm having issues where it's taking very long to run a match against this query. I'm trying to match up content that looks like the following:

```
One or more content paragraph of any length
Here is an optional paragraph

A single line or list item
A single line or list item
```

Here is my pattern. While it works for short expressions, it fails for longer ones.

```
^((.+[\r\n]?)+)\r\n\r\n([* -]*(.+)[\r\n]?)+$
```

My goal really is to separate out the first piece of content into a paragraph, and collect the last items into a list object using the matching pattern. I'm assuming two line breaks separate the paragraph(s) and a set of single-line items (only one line break).

Hope this isn't confusing. How can I optimize this regex? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you would like to see from the example you give above?

Comment: If all the items look exactly the same (with now errors) you can just use line reader to split them and convert (every two alternate) strings into list.

Comment: The title and first part of your question is about performance, then you say it "fails for longer ones". Is the regex too slow or does it not even function the way you want it to?

Comment: Feedback would be appreciated on how my answer does or does not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time-consuming, inefficient [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) can often be avoided by adding the `?` modifier to the `*` and `+` quantifiers to make them match *lazily* or *reluctantly*, i.e. as few times as possible.

This can be particularly important when the quantifiers follow the `.` wildcard meta-character.

Try

```
(.+?)\r\n\r\n(?:[* -]*(.+?)(?:\r\n|$))+
```

with `RegexOptions.Singleline` so `.` matches any character *including* newlines.
(Alternatively use `[\s\S]` in place of the first `.`).

The first capture group will capture all that comes before the consecutive newlines, and then the next capture groups will capture each single line that follows. As in your regex, any leading `*`, `-` or space characters in the single lines will not be captured.

The paragraph/s will be `match.Groups[1].Value`, the first captured single line will be `match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value` and the second `match.Groups[2].Captures[1].Value)` etc.

If the line-endings may be simply `\n`, change `\r\n` to `\r?\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good at regex but your one seems quite optimized to me. But to make it faster, use split instead to seperate the paragraph from the list

```
res = yourstring.Split('\r\n\r\n');
paragraph = res[0];
list=res[1];
```

then you can use regex or again split to seperate the list items from each other